# Asterisk CallerID name

Tags: asterisk

I have an IVR connected to `spa400`.

`spa400` has 4 FXO ports so I can connect 4 telephone lines to it. The problem is that when call comes I don't know from which line it is coming. `spa400` and IVR are connected through Ethernet. I read somewhere about `PORTIDs` but I don't know how to get them.

Someone posted [this](http://www.pbxinaflash.com/community/index.php?threads/spa400-port-selection.6250/) on the following link but I don't get it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What that link is saying is that the PORT_IDs you set on the SPA400 will be suffixes in Asterisk's ${CALLERID(name)}.